# How to localize Android's google map with a specific region (to comply with local boundaries and laws)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using Google Maps in my Android native app, and i am having an issue with my country's boundaries, its showing a dotted line in an area that suffers from a territorial dispute with another country =s.

I have total respect to the other country but my app is dedicated for people of my country thus it's not acceptable to have such a thing ^^''.

So how can i force Google Map SDK to load a map version specific to my country?

In the web version of my app (using Google Maps Javascript), i found an easy solution just by adding the paremeter "&region=Country_Code" in the api link, (based on this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization ). but in native Android i couldn't find any solution.

So, I need a way to pass the "region" to the google map sdk so it will load a localized version of the map as in the web.

Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: Could you check if the Google Maps App displays different borders on your phone? Perhaps this is tied to the locale of the phone itself.

Comment: How can i change the local of the phone? i can only change the language (android pie)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the locale that uses your application applying the following code
snapshot

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
  Locale locale = new Locale(current.getLanguage());
  Locale.setDefault(locale);
  Configuration config = new Configuration();
  config.locale = locale;
  getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Also, I would suggest starring a feature request for setting region bias in Google Maps Android SDK:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63829150

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i have tried this solution before but with no luck :s

Comment: Unfortunately we have to wait when Google implements a feature request I mentioned in the answer. Currently it looks like Android Maps SDK doesn't provide any mechanism to set region bias programmatically.